# C Program Generates An odd output

Tags: c

Recently I have tried to start learning C, and decided to do some of the project Euler challenges. I wrote this code to solve the problem, however when it is run it outputs numbers that should be impossible. I have tried everything to fix it. Including making some of my ints long, none of this seems to work. Any input would be great, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char num[] = 
"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
"96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
"85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
"12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
"66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
"62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
"30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
"70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
"65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
"52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
"53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
"83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
"82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
"16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
"17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
"24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
"07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
"84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
"05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
"71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    int inc;
    long int next_biggest = 0;
    for (inc = 0; inc <= 986; inc++){
        int temp;
        long int total = (int)num[inc];
        for (temp = 1; temp <= 13; temp++){
            total *= (int)num[(inc + temp)];
        }
        if ((total > next_biggest)){
            next_biggest = total;
            printf("Next Biggest Number: %ld\n", total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What numbers do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: Why are you casting `char` to `int ` when your variable is `long int`? But most important, you need to subtract `'0'` from the each string value to get a numeric value `0..9`. Project Euler problem #8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
long int total = (int)num[inc];
```

looks like it converts `'3'` into an `int` 3, but it does not. What it does is it takes the ASCII value of the `'3'` and assigns it to your `int`.

Fix it and your program would run fine :)

```
long int total = num[inc] - '0';
```

Essentially what is happening here is we get a `char` value (which is a digit) and get its ASCII code. Then, based on the fact that in ASCII all the digits are in one contiguous block of values that begins with '0' we calculate the face value of that digits and use it as an `int`.

Here's the output of your program once the above line is corrected:

> Next Biggest Number: 2032807552
>   Next Biggest Number: 2084481664
>   Next Biggest Number: 2141716480
>   Next Biggest Number: 2144206848

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. Ill look into a different way to do it

Comment: Are you going to explain how to fix it?

Comment: oh, I didn't? My bad :) Explained the fix now.

Comment: The character is a codepoint, meaning it is a number that references a glyph, which is something that is drawn to the screen.  That means that a char that holds '0' doesn't have the value of (numeric) 0.  Fortunately the people who chose the code points for ASCII put the characters '0'..'9' in order, so to get numeric 0, you do '0' - '0' and to get numeric 5 you do '5' - '0'.  Beyond that the rest of your code looks ok Enjoy.

Comment: The cast isn't required in this case, since `long int` can contain all values of `char` and therefore an implicit conversion happens.

Comment: @dbush - it is a valid point. Indeed the upcast doesn't need to be explicit.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't rely on the usage of ASCII. The C specification requires that '0' through '9' be sequential regardless of which character set is being used.  The alphabet, OTOH, is not required to be sequential.

Comment: I didn't know that. Could you find the reference for me? I'm trying but not able to so far (and I've been bitten by EBCIDIC and Shift-JIS too many times before, so...)

Comment: This is the C standard, but I can't seem to find the mention of the digits '0'-'9' being sequential: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.open-std.org%2Fjtc1%2Fsc22%2Fwg14%2Fwww%2Fdocs%2Fn1570.pdf

Comment: In the C11 draft, it's section 5.2.1 **Character sets**, paragraph 3.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use atoi(), atol() eg.. to convert a char or array or chars to a single int or long type.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

You can do it like this and it will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buffer[256] = {"123456"};
char i = buffer[3];
printf("%d", atoi(&i) );
```

Soo I would do it like this:

```
int inc;
char convert;
long int next_biggest = 0;
for (inc = 0; inc <= 986; inc++){
    int temp;
    convert = num[inc];
    long int total = atol(&convert);
    for (temp = 1; temp <= 13; temp++){
        convert = num[(inc + temp)];
        total *= atol(&convert);
    }
    if ((total > next_biggest)){
        next_biggest = total;
        printf("Next Biggest Number: %ld\n", total);
    }
}
```

So the basic idea is like.. I haven't tested but it should work like this. using ATOL for long.  Note,  you don't need a long with the single characters.  Single characters are usually never over 255 unsigned and 128 signed.

Comment: Your suggestion does not work in his case as he is specifically processing one digit at a time

Comment: If you assign to a char first.  Then it can be processed like shown above.  I should have added that.. Thanks for pointing that out.